# Declare string constants for date formats instead of explicitly having to write string values

Tags: java, c#, date, datetime, design-patterns

Is it advisable / good programming practice to store date formats as string constants which can then be used throughout a web application?

For instance, instead of writing `.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")` in code-behind, one would use `.ToString(MyDateClass.DateFormat1)`. If `.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")` is used elsewhere, we would create MyDateClass.DateFormat2 and use `.ToString(MyDateClass.DateFormat2)`.

For JS code one could for instance have global string variables for `"dd.MM.yyyy"` and `"yyyy.MM.dd"` and these will be used instead.

Comment: This is an opinion based question which it would be more appropriate to post on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. For what it's worth, my opinion is yes - I have done this myself, using meaningful names for the date format constants.

Comment: @redbirdo Being opinion-based does not make something appropriate to post on Programmers.SE. This question is technically on-topic for us, but it would get closed quickly as too broad/unclear/opinion-based.

Comment: Your date-time library may already define some useful patterns. Sensible formats specified by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard are pre-defined in both [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html).

Comment: @redbirdo Thanks! Will try programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's standard practice and should be extended to other "magic strings" that are used in your application, such as regular expressions. I tend to use constant files in my projects where I can group together logically related constants and refer to them in other classes and projects.

If a constant is used widely the scope of the constants file should reflect that - if the scope is more narrow, consider using a more localised file, or in some cases just put the constants in the class file itself, if the use of it is limited to that class.

I would also advise that the names you use reflect the meaning, e.g., instead of DateFormat1 and DateFormat2 use something like DateFormatDDMMYYYY and DateFormatYYYYMMDD.

Comment: I understand that magic strings should be avoided as far as possible. But, if one considers that the format for the date fields won't be changed that often (possibly never) in the application, would it still make sense to systematically create constants for each date format instead of plainly stating the string value itself? Seems like extra code that would need to be maintained?

Comment: Suppose you decide that instead of dates being displayed in the format "dd.MM.yyyy" you now want to display them as "dd/MM/yyyy". If you've used your constant throughout your application, simply changing the value of that one item will cause all the dates in the application to be displayed in the new format, so yes, it is still worth it. Besides, as you say, if the date formats change infrequently, there'll be no need for any maintenance of the constants file.

Comment: I would argue that names like 'DateFormatDDMMYYYY' are not meaningful and would actually become misleading if the format changed. Meaningful might be e.g. DATE_FORMAT_SHORT, DATE_FORMAT_LIST or DATE_FORMAT_MONTH_YEAR etc depending on the contexts in which a particular format will be used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an enum class for representing your dateFormats.

For example like this:

```
public enum DateFormat {

    dd_MM_yyyy {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "dd.MM.yyyy";
        }
    },
    yyyy_MM_dd {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "yyyy.MM.dd";
        }
    }
}
```

and then just use the enum: `DateFormat.dd_MM_yyyy.toString();`

Comment: Good answer, extept that overriding the [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) on an enum is recommended only for programmer use (debugging/logging) not business logic. For productive use, add a method to the enum specifically to your purpose. In this case, rendering the format pattern. Name the method something like `DateFormat.dd_MM_yyyy.pattern()`.

Comment: You have missing curly `{}` brackets in above code, causing compilation erros. Please update it.

Comment: @BasilBourque Tested on java 12 and your way is not working. I have no clue if it has something to do with the new java 12. But its not working. It gives me a compilation error.

Comment: @Merv I posted [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58478829/642706) and an Answer showing how to hold a few `DateTimeFormatter` objects within a Java enum.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks bro. But I just made a new class and used constants.