# Define a few specific date formatters as members of an enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, java-time, formatter, dateformatter

I need to track a few formats ([`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) objects) for repeated use in my app.

➥ How to represent these formatter objects by using a Java enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

Yes.

```
FormatDateOnly.DD_MM_YYYY.getFormatter()
```

## Details

Yes, you can easily store some [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) objects in an enum.

The slick [enum facility in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is quite powerful and flexible.

Basically, an enum in Java is almost a normal Java class. Your enum can have member variables to store objects internally. Your enum can have a constructor, and you can pass arguments to those constructors. You can define methods on your enum.

Let's put those 3 features together in this example class, `FormatDateOnly` enum class.

We define 3 objects in this enum, named `DD_MM_YYYY`, `YYYY_MM_DD`, and `MM_DD_YYYY`. When constructing each, we assign a `DateTimeFormatter` object to be held in this enum. Because *java.time* classes ([tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)) are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and designed to be [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), we can hold a single instance for reuse even across threads. The way enums work in Java is that an instance of that when our class `FormatDateOnly` is first loaded, each of our three constructors is called to make an instance assigned to each name.

We also pass a string to use as the display-name of each enum. We see this used in the `toString` override method.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public enum FormatDateOnly
{
    DD_MM_YYYY( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" ) , "DD.MM.YYYY" ),
    YYYY_MM_DD( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu.MM.dd" ) , "YYYY.MM.DD" ),
    MM_DD_YYYY( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM.dd.uuuu" ) , "MM.DD.YYYY" );

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter;
    private String displayName;

    FormatDateOnly ( DateTimeFormatter formatter , String displayName )
    {
        this.formatter = formatter;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "LocalDateFormat{" +
                "displayName='" + this.displayName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public DateTimeFormatter getFormatter ( )
    {
        return this.formatter;
    }

    public String getDisplayName ( )
    {
        return this.displayName;
    }
}
```

To use these enums, we refer to the desired enum object, then call the getter method to retrieve the stored `DateTimeFormatter` stored within that enum object.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );

String output1 = localDate.format( FormatDateOnly.DD_MM_YYYY.getFormatter() );
String output2 = localDate.format( FormatDateOnly.MM_DD_YYYY.getFormatter() );
String output3 = localDate.format( FormatDateOnly.YYYY_MM_DD.getFormatter() );
```

- The first part `FormatDateOnly.DD_MM_YYYY` refers to one of the three pre-existing objects (instantiated when class loaded).
- The second part, `.getFormatter()` invokes the getter method on that particular enum object to retrieve the existing `DateTimeFormatter` object passed to the enum’s constructor.

Dump to console. Running on Java 13.

```
System.out.println( "localDate.toString() = " + localDate );
System.out.println( "output1 = " + output1 );
System.out.println( "output2 = " + output2 );
System.out.println( "output3 = " + output3 );
```

> localDate.toString() = 2020-01-23
>
> output1 = 23.01.2020
>
> output2 = 01.23.2020
>
> output3 = 2020.01.23

---

By the way, I am not necessarily recommending this arrangement. Generally it is better to let *java.time* [automatically localize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) when generating text representing a date-time object. Specify a [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) for how long or abbreviate you want the resulting string. Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms needed for localization.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = localDate.format( formatter ) ;
```

> 20-01-23

Comment: @Andreas Good point. I modified code to use `displayName` to match the convention on the *java.time* classes such as `Month::getDisplayName`.

Comment: I would recommend moving the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(...)` call inside the constructor ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), and to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.US)`

Comment: @Andreas I'll let your comment do the work of raising that valid issue. [The post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152926/declare-string-constants-for-date-formats-instead-of-explicitly-having-to-write/35153197?noredirect=1#comment103289107_35153197) that inspired this page was quite specific about the particular needs.  By sticking to those needs I get the benefit of keeping this example here as simple as possible, to make the basic point of an object being stored with an enum.

Comment: @Andreas I had already covered thread-safety. Now I added links to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Formating the same approach can be used for **parsing** also

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public enum StandardDateParser {
    YYYY_MM_DD(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
    YYYYMMDD(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"), "yyyyMMdd"),
    YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
    YYYY_MM_DDTHH_MM_SSZ(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    SimpleDateFormat parser;
    private String displayName;

    StandardDateParser(SimpleDateFormat parser, String displayName) {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public SimpleDateFormat getParser() {
        return this.parser;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return this.displayName;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = StandardDateParser.YYYY_MM_DDTHH_MM_SSZ.getParser();
Date date;
try {
    date = parser.parse(INPUT_STRING)
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // your fall back code
}
```

Comment: Only don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That is a notorious troublemaker of a class. The modern `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time was wisely asked about.

Comment: how can I parse String Date using DateTimeFormatter, the parse method returns java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor @OleV.V.

Comment: Thanks, @Rajat, for asking. You shouldn’t want to use `Date` either, it too is poorly designed and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` as in the other answer, `LocalDateTIme`or `OffsetDateTime`  and [the two-arg `parse` method of the appropriate class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html). (Parsing both formats with and without time of day and/or UTC offset isn’t that trivial, though, and you should first of all be precise about expected results.)

Comment: If you need an old-fashioned `Date` for a legacy API (that would have to be *really old* by now), conversions are available, for example `Date.from(yourParsedLocalDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())`.